# How to install PYODBC in Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc, databricks, azure-databricks

I have to install pyodbc module in Databricks.
I have tried using this command (`pip install pyodbc`) but it is failed due to below error.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxmGG.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had some problems a while back with connecting using pyobdc, details of my fix are here: https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/10/12/executing-sql-server-stored-procedures-on-databricks-pyspark

I think the problem stems from PYTHONPATH on the databricks clusters being set to the Python 2 install.

I suspect the lines:

```
%sh    
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
/databricks/python/bin/pip install pyodbc
```

Will work for you.

Update: Even simpler (though you will still need unixodbc-dev from above):

```
%sh 
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
pip3 install --upgrade pyodbc
```

Comment: What version of python is your cluster running?

Comment: Thanks Fabio,i have tried the comment.but i'm still getting this error(E:could not get lock and unable to lock the administration directory(var/lib/dpkng),is another process using it?).could please help me on that

Comment: Thanks simon,i have tried the command in databricks  but it is showing as cancelled.please suggest if there is any alternative to do this.

Comment: Thanks, Fabio the command is working and pyodbc got installed. But while connecting to the SQL server, i'm facing this error (('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")).Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Did you read the link I gave on the answer above? It explains how to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Fabio and Simon command works fine and I'm able to connect to sql server.

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same issue for installation. This is what I tried and it worked.

- Databricks does not have default ODBC Driver. Run following commands in a single cell to install MS SQL ODBC driver

```
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17
```

- Run this in notebook

```
dbutils.fs.put("/databricks/init/<YourClusterName>/pyodbc-install.sh","""
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -q -y install unixodbc unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get -q -y install python3-dev
/databricks/python/bin/pip install pyodbc
""", True)
```

- Restart the cluster
- Import pyodbc in Code

Comment: This answer won't work for the new Databricks runtime because cluster-named init scripts have been deprecated. Please read the link from the above answer and create an init script for the cluster scope. It works for me this way.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the Workspace folder where you want to store the library.

Select Create > Library.

Look this https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/libraries.html for detailed information

Comment: Thanks Fabio,But i have already tried the same thing.after uploading the .whl file also i'm getting the same error as in the screen shot.Could please help me on this?