# How to INSERT INTO Azure SQL database from Azure Databricks in Python

Tags: python, jdbc, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks

Since pyodbc cannot be installed to Azure databricks, I am trying to use jdbc to insert data into Azure SQL database by Python, but I can find sample code for that.

```
jdbcHostname = "xxxxxxx.database.windows.net"
jdbcDatabase = "yyyyyy"
jdbcPort = 1433
#jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2};user={3};password={4}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase, username, password)

jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : jdbcUsername,
  "password" : jdbcPassword,
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}

pushdown_query = "(INSERT INTO test (a, b) VALUES ('val_a', 'val_b')) insert_test"
```

Please advise how to write insertion code in Python.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since pyodbc cannot be installed to Azure databricks

Actually, it seems you could install pyodbc in databricks.

```
%sh    
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
/databricks/python/bin/pip install pyodbc
```

For more details, you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54133228/9455659) and this [blog](https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/10/12/executing-sql-server-stored-procedures-on-databricks-pyspark).

Comment: @jay wang, Thanks, it worked, and additionally I needed to add '%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
pip3 install --upgrade pyodbc' on  [link] (https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/10/12/executing-sql-server-stored-procedures-on-databricks-pyspark)

Answer (score 3):

If I may add, you should also be able to use a Spark data frame to insert to Azure SQL. Just use the connection string you get from Azure SQL.

```
connectionString = "<Azure SQL Connection string>"

data = spark.createDataFrame([(val_a, val_b)], ["a", "b"])

data.write.jdbc(connectionString, "<TableName>", mode="append")
```

Answer (score 0):

Pigging backing on Jon ... This is what I used to write data from a Azure databricks dataframe to a Azure SQL Database:

```
    Hostname = "YOUR_SERVER.database.windows.net"
    Database = "YOUR_DB"
    port = 1433
    UN = 'YOUR_USERNAME'
    PW = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
    Url = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2};user={3};password= {4}".format(Hostname, Port, Database, UN, PW)

   df.write.jdbc(Url, "schema.table", mode="append")
```