# How can I configure Oracle Driver Manager on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, azure, azure-databricks

I have a system developed in Microsoft Azure, more precisely in Databricks.
My challenge is to connect to an external Oracle database, but after numerous attempts, the same error is generated:

Code in python:

```
import pyodbc
try1 = 'Devart ODBC Driver for Oracle'
try2 = 'Microsoft ODBC for Oracle'
try3 = 'Oracle'
try4 = 'Oracle ODBC driver for Oracle 11g'

conn_str = ('DRIVER={'+try3+'};'+'SERVER=server;'+'DATABASE=db;'+'UID=uid;'+'PWD=pwd;')

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

Error message:

```
('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Oracle' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can solve it in the Azure environment?

Very Thanks!

Comment: Please include the code and error message as text, and not an image, to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting ODBC drivers installed in Databricks is a bit of a hassle, as you have to provide startup bash scripts to install and configure the drivers.

[JDBC driver install](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries.html#libraries) is simpler, as you just upload the library.

So if possible, use Spark and JDBC instead of pyodbc.  See https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/oracle.html

If you need to do things other than simply Spark reads and loads, you can always use a [Scala or Java cell with JDBC](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html).

Comment: I need to execute a procedure in Oracle with dynamics parameters, I believe this solution does not help me, correct?

Comment: Scala/Java and JDBC is a first-class Oracle client, well documented and fully supported.  For complicated tasks it’s a better bet than pyodbc.

Comment: So, I cant use Spark like u mentioned?: "So if possible, use Spark and JDBC instead of pyodbc. See https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/oracle.html"

Comment: You can use Spark for reading tables and queries into Data Frames, and for writing Data Frames into tables.  But you can't use Spark to run a stored procedure, you have do "drop down" to Java or Scala and use the JDBC API directly.

Comment: David, in the link that passed me: 
"https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html"
says that I must execute one of the following commands: "Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")" or "Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")". To consume an Oracle driver, I understand that I must execute the command "Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")", but returns the following error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver". Do I need to configure something in the Databricks environment to install the driver I need?

Comment: You need to download (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html) and install (https://docs.databricks.com/libraries.html#libraries)  the Oracle JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Azure Databricks does not have Oracle ODBC Driver installed.

Run the following commands in a single cell to install Oracle ODBC Driver on Azure Databricks cluster.

```
%sh    
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
/databricks/python/bin/pip install pyodbc
```

Once, the you have installed Oracle ODBC Driver on Azure Databricks cluster, you can connect Oracle database.

For more details, refer the below threads, which addressing similar issue.

[How to install PYODBC in Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132249/how-to-install-pyodbc-in-databricks)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5bb3d872-613f-4738-b9d6-bc1dba32a354/unable-to-connect-to-sql-database-using-rodbc?forum=AzureDatabricks

Hope this helps.