# update table from Pyspark using JDBC

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks

I have a small `log` dataframe which has metadata regarding the `ETL` performed within a given notebook, the notebook is part of a bigger `ETL` pipeline managed in Azure DataFactory.

Unfortunately, it seems that Databricks cannot invoke stored procedures so I'm manually appending a row with the correct data to my log table.

however, I cannot figure out the correct sytnax to update a table given a set of conditions :

the statement I use to append a single row is as follows :

```
spark_log.write.jdbc(sql_url, 'internal.Job',mode='append')
```

this works swimmingly however, as my Data Factory is invoking a stored procedure,

I need to work in a query like

```
query  = f"""
UPDATE [internal].[Job] SET
     [MaxIngestionDate]                date                   {date}
,    [DataLakeMetadataRaw]            varchar(MAX)            NULL
,    [DataLakeMetadataCurated]        varchar(MAX)            NULL
WHERE [IsRunning] = 1
AND [FinishDateTime] IS NULL"""
```

Is this possible ? if so can someone show me how?

Looking at the documentation this only seems to mention using `select` statements with the `query` parameter :

Target Database is an Azure SQL Database.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

just to add this is a tiny operation, so performance is a non-issue.

Comment: to any lost souls wondering here, my work around was to pass a json blob on the completion of the notebook in my datafactory pipeline which i then parsed out and pass as parameters to my Stored Proc which in turn updated my log tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do single record updates using jdbc in Spark with dataframes.  You can only append or replace the entire table.

You can do updates using pyodbc- requires installing the MSSQL ODBC driver ([How to install PYODBC in Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132249/how-to-install-pyodbc-in-databricks)) or you can use jdbc via JayDeBeApi (https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/)