pyodbc-databricks-('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0)(SQLDriverConnect)")
I am doing a SQL operation in Azure Databricks and for that, I am importing the ODBC driver.
Below is the code and this is uploaded to the cluster as init script.
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
pip3 install --upgrade pyodbc

And this is script used to connect to the server.
    connect_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
    connect_string += f"SERVER={jdbchostname},"
    connect_string += f"{jdbcport};"
    connect_string += f"DATABASE={db};"
    connect_string += f"UID={username};"
    connect_string += f"PWD={pwd}"

    conn = pyodbc.connect(connect_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

This script throws an error.

('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC
Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")


If you install the driver interactively, do you get any error messages? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78027790/1690193

@Nick.Mc yes, that is why i moved it to init script.

Instead of installing an ODBC driver or adding to the init script, you can use a JDBC driver to connect to an SQL server. Use the code below:
jdbcHostname = "<servername>.database.windows.net"     
jdbcPort = 1433    
jdbcDatabase = "<dbname>"     
jdbcUsername = "<username>"             
jdbcPassword = "<password>"            
jdbcDriver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"     
table = "<tableName>"
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort};databaseName={jdbcDatabase}"
df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", jdbcDriver).option("url", jdbcUrl).option("dbtable", table).option("user", jdbcUsername).option("password", jdbcPassword).load()

This will connect to the SQL server successfully, as shown below:

